# Increase the price of taxi booking on a certain date

Tags: php

I need help with the following problem:

I have a car hire service (written in PHP). The quote for the taxi hire is retrieved from the DB when users enter pick up and drop off point. Then they are navigated to the booking / reservation form.

I want to be able to increase the price of that quote based on a certain date range. For instance say Olympics time in London. If the customer choses that date range, I would like to increase the price by certain % or add a surcharge.

Any easy way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is trivial.  Determine if [`time()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.time.php) falls between a date range, and if so, charge taxi patrons more!

```
$startdate = '2012-06-01';
$enddate = '2012-06-14';
$now = time();

// 5% surcharge
$surcharge = 0.05;
if ($now >= strtotime($startdate) && $now <= strtotime($enddate)) {
  // Calculate & add the surcharge.
  $price += ($price * $surcharge);
}
```

#### Update after comments

Since you have received the price before selecting a date, and the price is apparently stored in `$contents['journeyprice']`, you would need to store it in `$_SESSION` and retrieve later to do the calculation after the dates are submitted.  That is, unless you can change the logic to select the dates first.  Given that the price may change after being first displayed, it would make sense to me instead to choose dates before seeing the initial price.

However, store it in `$_SESSION` with:

```
// session_start() was called earlier in the script, we assume
$_SESSION['price'] = $content['journeyprice'];
```

Then on the script that receives the date choices, retrieve the price:

```
session_start();
$price = $_SESSION['price'];
// Do the calculation as above...
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but slightly confused as of how to implement the codes. the quote is displaed via <?php echo $contents['journeyprice']; ?>    and the date is then chosen and submited, now since the date is chosen after allready getting a price, where or how do i use the above code? thank you

Comment: The code given by Michael isn't meant to be implemented directly, but just as an example of how to manipulate the variables appropriately.

Comment: @Shad see info added above. But without seeing your code all this is speculative.